# PHP - Turn this string: "adc 25...123.50 xyz" into 2 variables: "25" and "123.50"?

Tags: php, preg-replace

The title almost much sums what i am trying to accomplish.

I have a string that could consist of letters in the alphabet or, numbers or characters like ")" and "*". It may also include a numeric string separated by three dots "...", e.g. "25...123.50".

An example of this string could be:

`peaches* 25...123.50 +("apples")` or `-(peaches*) apples* 25...123.50`

Now, what i would like to do is capture the numbers before and after the three dots, so i end up with 2 variables, `25` and `123.50`. I would then like to trim the string so that i end up with a string that excludes the number values:

`peaches* +("apples")` or `-(peaches*) apples*`

So essentially:

```
$string = 'peaches* 25...123.50 +("apples")';
if (preg_match("/\.\.\./", $string ))
{
    # How do i get the left value (could or could not be a decimal, using .)
    $from = 25; 
    # How do i get the right value (could or could not be a decimal, using .)
    $to = 123.50;
    # How do i remove the value "here...here" is this right?
    $clean = preg_replace('/'.$from.'\.\.\.'.$to.'/', '', $string);
    $clean = preg_replace('/  /', ' ', $string);
}
```

If anyone could provide me with some input on the best way to go about this complicated task it would be greatly appreciated! Any suggestions, advice, input, feedback or comments are most welcome, Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This preg_match should work:

```
$str = 'peaches* 25...123.50 +("apples")';
if (preg_match('~(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\.{3}(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)~', $str, $arr))
   print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Yep! Now you just would need to remove each of the array elements from the string and repeat in a loop til you are done.

Answer (score 1):

*Pseudo code*

In a loop:

Perform a **strpos** for "..." and **substr** at that position. Then go back from the end of that substring (character by character), checking to see if each **is_numeric** or a **period**. On the first non-numeric/non-period occurrence, you grab a substring from the beginning of the original string to that point (store it temporarily). Then start checking for is_numeric or period in the other direction. Grab a substring and add it to the other substring you stored. Repeat.

It's not a regex, but it will accomplish the same goal nonetheless.

*Some php*

```
$my_string = "blah blah abc25.4...123.50xyz blah blah etc";
$found = 1;

while($found){

    $found = $cursor = strpos($my_string , "...");

    if(!empty($found)){

        //Go left
        $char = ".";
        while(is_numeric($char) || $char == "."){
            $cursor--;
            $char = substr($my_string , $cursor, 1);
        } 
        $left_substring = substr($my_string , 1, $cursor);

        //Go right
        $cursor = $found + 2;
        $char = ".";
        while(is_numeric($char) || $char == "."){
            $cursor++;
            $char = substr($my_string , $cursor, 1);
        } 
        $right_substring = substr($my_string , $cursor);

        //Combine the left and right
        $my_string = $left_substring . $right_substring;
    }
}

echo $my_string;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your feedback and yes that does make sense, it will take some thought i guess as i am not that clued up on the str functions. Are you suggesting that i use something like `strstr()`? that would maybe capture the first part but is there and opposite of this that would make the task easier? `Then go back from the end of that substring (character by character)`: This is a bit confusing i wont lie :)

Comment: I wrote it straight in the stackoverflow edit box, so you would need to debug it, or just mentally walk through it to get the sense of how it's attacking the problem. You'll also have to confirm whether some of these PHP functions (substr, strpos) start at position 0, or position 1 for the first character. I forget.